# Why does the JVM crash with a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace" even though Metaspace is not filled up?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, metaspace

I am currently investigating one interesting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace" issue. Reason I think it is "interesting" as because Metaspace usage was far less than maximum Metaspace size(1GB). Heap and GC configurations are:

```
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_92-b14), built on Mar 31 2016 21:03:04 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
Memory: 4k page, physical 29359668k(24768956k free), swap 37748276k(29744220k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=314572800 -XX:GCLogFileSize=104857600 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=4294967296 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=6442450944 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1073741824 -XX:MetaspaceSize=536870912 -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20  -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

Following are the last 6 GC events before JVM crashed:

```
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.001800 major_cost: 0.000613 mutator_cost: 0.997587 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1064594816 free_space: 2587885568 old_eden_size: 1486356480 desired_eden_size: 1443889152
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_old_gen_free_space: costs minor_time: 0.001800 major_cost: 0.000613 mutator_cost: 0.997587 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1095533824 free_space: 2545418240 old_promo_size: 1101529088 desired_promo_size: 1078460416
AdaptiveSizePolicy::old generation size: collection: 1121 (2867855360) -> (2863661056) 
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 1121 
[PSYoungGen: 4825K->0K(1456640K)] [ParOldGen: 2799035K->902778K(2796544K)] 2803860K->902778K(4253184K), [Metaspace: 330658K->329502K(614400K)], 1.0547274 secs] [Times: user=3.03 sys=0.00, real=1.06 secs] 
2020-02-05T07:47:01.085-0500: 23601.918: [GC (Allocation Failure) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 55971960  promoted: 8192  overflow: false
AdaptiveSizeStart: 23601.976 collection: 1122 
  avg_survived_padded_avg: 107655896.000000  avg_promoted_padded_avg: 77367808.000000  avg_pretenured_padded_avg: 0.000000  tenuring_thresh: 1  target_size: 108003328
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.001995 major_cost: 0.000613 mutator_cost: 0.997392 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1098490112 free_space: 2522349568 old_eden_size: 1443889152 desired_eden_size: 1443364864
AdaptiveSizePolicy::survivor space sizes: collection: 1122 (106954752, 524288) -> (56098816, 108003328) 
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 1122 
[PSYoungGen: 1451520K->54660K(1464320K)] 2354298K->957446K(4260864K), 0.0585204 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2020-02-05T07:47:02.815-0500: 23603.648: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 10372288  promoted: 54161296  overflow: false
AdaptiveSizeStart: 23603.701 collection: 1123 
  avg_survived_padded_avg: 104833904.000000  avg_promoted_padded_avg: 84380448.000000  avg_pretenured_padded_avg: 0.000000  tenuring_thresh: 1  target_size: 104857600
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.009104 major_cost: 0.000613 mutator_cost: 0.990283 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1096590848 free_space: 2521825280 old_eden_size: 1443364864 desired_eden_size: 1402470400
AdaptiveSizePolicy::survivor space sizes: collection: 1123 (10485760, 56098816) -> (10485760, 104857600) 
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 1123 
[PSYoungGen: 221390K->10129K(1379840K)] 1124177K->965807K(4176384K), 0.0625170 secs] [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2020-02-05T07:47:02.878-0500: 23603.711: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) AdaptiveSizeStart: 23604.878 collection: 1124 
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.009104 major_cost: 0.012509 mutator_cost: 0.978387 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1093844224 free_space: 2480930816 old_eden_size: 1402470400 desired_eden_size: 1520959488
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_old_gen_free_space: costs minor_time: 0.009104 major_cost: 0.012509 mutator_cost: 0.978387 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1097600256 free_space: 2599419904 old_promo_size: 1078460416 desired_promo_size: 1328545792
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 1124 
[PSYoungGen: 10129K->0K(1379840K)] [ParOldGen: 955678K->804848K(2796544K)] 965807K->804848K(4176384K), [Metaspace: 336946K->336898K(620544K)], 1.1672615 secs] [Times: user=3.28 sys=0.00, real=1.17 secs] 
2020-02-05T07:47:04.046-0500: 23604.879: [GC (Last ditch collection) AdaptiveSizePolicy::update_averages:  survived: 0  promoted: 0  overflow: false
AdaptiveSizeStart: 23604.893 collection: 1125 
  avg_survived_padded_avg: 103366768.000000  avg_promoted_padded_avg: 82075424.000000  avg_pretenured_padded_avg: 0.000000  tenuring_thresh: 2  target_size: 103809024
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.009750 major_cost: 0.012509 mutator_cost: 0.977741 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1095128320 free_space: 2849505280 old_eden_size: 1520959488 desired_eden_size: 1525678080
AdaptiveSizePolicy::survivor space sizes: collection: 1125 (104857600, 10485760) -> (104857600, 103809024) 
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 1125 
[PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(1513984K)] 804848K->804848K(4310528K), 0.0142603 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-02-05T07:47:04.061-0500: 23604.893: [Full GC (Last ditch collection) AdaptiveSizeStart: 23607.663 collection: 1126 
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.009750 major_cost: 0.258044 mutator_cost: 0.732206 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1092903552 free_space: 2854223872 old_eden_size: 1525678080 desired_eden_size: 1456472064
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_old_gen_free_space: costs minor_time: 0.009750 major_cost: 0.258044 mutator_cost: 0.732206 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 1093117440 free_space: 2785017856 old_promo_size: 1328545792 desired_promo_size: 1713373184
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 1126 
[PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(1513984K)] [ParOldGen: 804848K->787083K(2796544K)] 804848K->787083K(4310528K), [Metaspace: 336962K->328764K(620544K)], 2.7696424 secs] [Times: user=6.91 sys=0.03, real=2.77 secs]
```

If you look at the very last Metaspace usage, it was around ~328MB:
`[Metaspace: 336962K->328764K(620544K)]`

According to [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html): "MaxMetaspaceSize applies to the sum of the committed compressed class space and the space for the other class metadata.". I also checked compressed class space usage, it was ~50MB.

I checked the Virtual Memory usage. There was no shortage. This is where I am confused. As you can see Metaspace usage was <50% of the MaxMetaspaceSize, then why JVM was doing "Last ditch collection" and running into OOM? Am I running into some JDK bug? Also it is not those "one-off" cases, it happens once/twice a month. I am not sure if I am missing something, can someone please share their thoughts?

Comment: are you sure you don't get "Compressed Class Space OOM"?

Comment: @Eugene, yes I am 100% sure about that. As per stdout log, it is always Metaspace OOM. In that JVM compressed class space size is 300MB and actual usage was around 50MB.

Comment: ok, so it seems you are aware of that since you enabled `UseCompressedClassPointers`, you are going to get : `MaxMetaspaceSize = CompressedClassSpaceSize + "other metaspace"` (around that), where `CompressedClassSpaceSize` is around 300MB in your case and "other metaspace" is going to be around `600MB`. So from your logs - you have around "300MB" free, but GC still fails. The issue here _might_ be with fragmentation of metaspace - you _do_ have space, but it is not continuous and it might fail. (continue:)

Comment: we have not had this problem, but we use `jemalloc` via : `LD_PRELOAD=..../libjemalloc.so` that seems to take care of this fragmentation (as opposed to `malloc`).

Comment: @Eugene, fragmentation is a possibility _but_ till now I do not have any data to identify that. As Java version is bit old jdk_1.8.92, I cannot use `VM.metaspace` on the fly to extract data. I am planning to get `GC.class_stats` data periodically for couple of weeks to see if it indicates something. Also please let me know if you have any better approach to find fragmentation in Metaspace. Thanks you! :)

Comment: An interesting point is that it doesn’t seem like there was a failed allocation, but rather the GC was triggered due to the crossed threshold (`Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)`). But the times look very high. This section of the log is not enough to say that definitely, but it looks like the JVM was spending more time in GC than anything else. Perhaps, this is the equivalent to “GC overhead exceeded”, but since the last GC was triggered by the Metaspace ergonomics, it falls back to the misleading message “Metaspace”. Just a guess.

Comment: @Holger, No I am not seeing GC thrashing. Those 4 Full GCs occurred just before crash. Other than that, there was no Full GC.

Comment: Assuming that the “Last ditch collection” is the symptom of the problem, I even see only *one* Full GC here, labelled as “Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)”, which comes at no surprise, as you specified `-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50` and the metaspace usage crossed the 50% threshold. But this Full GC took 1.167 seconds, the preceding minor GC 0.063 secs, whereas the time between both and the previous allocation triggered GC was 1.67 seconds. That’s a really bad ratio, but not enough to make the JVM bail out. On the other hand, I see another GC >1s at the top, whose starting time is not included.

Comment: @Holger this is the intended behavior. When some metadata can't be allocated into metaspace, [this is triggered](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcVMOperations.cpp#l224). So it first triggers a [metadata threshold GC cause](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcVMOperations.cpp#l251) and if that did not help, it tries to [expand metaspace](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcVMOperations.cpp#l251)

Comment: I do not even see that `ditch` collection though in jdk-13 (but there are versions where it is present), I guess they removed it in "some" version. I am still inclined to say fragmentation here. Though I do not think that `jcmd <PID> VM.metaspace` will help (though I have only used it for fun, so my knowledge is limited). It seems that people much smarter than me (thanks Luke!) say to use `jcmd PID VM.classloader_stats` _or_ for your case : `jmap -clstats PID`.